# Python: Function that searches through a dictionary in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary

I have a question that goes like this

> Write the contract, docstring and implementation for a function findActor that takes a movie title and a character's name and returns the actor/actress that played the given character in the given movie. If the given movie or the given character is not found, it prints out an error message and returns an empty string

I have already done the following functions that will be of assistance for doing this.  And myIMDb is a global dictionary, set to an empty dic to start

```
def addMovie (title, charList, actList):
    """The function addMovie takes a title of the movie, a list of characters,
    and a list of actors. (The order of characters and actors match one
    another.) The function addMovie adds a pair to myIMDb. The key is the title
    of the movie while the value is a dictionary that matches characters to
    actors"""

    dict2 = {}
    for i in range (0, len(charList)):
        dict2 [charList[i]] = actList[i]
    myIMDb[len(myIMDb)] = {title: dict2}
    return myIMDb




def listMovies():
    """returns a list of titles of all the movies in the global variable myIMDb"""
    titles = []
    for i in range (len(myIMDb)):
        titles.append((list(myIMDb[i].keys())))
    return titles
```

Here's where I'm having problems.  When I want to write the findActor function I'm getting nothing to return.  I'm not finished with the function but I'm thinking that i've done something fundamentally wrong.  I feel like I'm going down the wrong road and I'm getting more and more lost the more I write.  Here's what I have so for.  Any suggestions for how to right this sinking ship would be appreciated.

```
def findActor(title, name):
    myIMDb = {}
    for i in range (len(myIMDb)):
        if title == myIMDb[i].keys():
            if name == myIMDb[i].get(name):
                return myIMDb[i].get(name)
        else:
            return "Error: No Movie found"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate your `myIMDB` dictionary in `findActor` before you use it.

In addition, I'd suggest mapping `myIMDB` directly from the title of the move to characters. In other words, instead of doing `myIMDb[len(myIMDb)] = {title: dict2}` in your `addMoive`, you should just do `myIMDb[title] = dict2`.

This way, when you need to look up the title and character, you can simply do:

```
def findActor(title, name):
    if title in myIMDb:
        if name in myIMDb[title]:
            return myIMDb[title][name]
    return "Error: No movie found"
```

Comment: I was populating myIMDb, I just forgot to say that I was.  I also did what you suggested.  And it threw off my, "listMovies" function, and I still get the same probelm with my findActor.  It's not returning anything, regardless of what I put in the parameters.

Comment: Hmm by not returning anything you mean it just doesn't return anything or it's returning the error? In your original code, since you also initialized `myIMDb` locally to an empty dictionary, as you loop through it you would just do nothing because there's nothing in the dictionary. Make sure you are using the global myIMDb instead of your local empty one.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, it was just a dumb tabbing mistake on my part.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to learn, programming in any language, is to reduce your task to sub-tasks. Here, why not start first with creating just a dictionary of roles and actors for a single movie. If you can't do that, then you won't be able to complete the full project.

After you work on that, maybe everything else will fall into place.

Warning: in the real world, occasionally more than one actor may play a role - for example - a role in which a child matures into adulthood. But that likely is not in your spec.

Comment: Aren't these typically listed as different roles in the database, though, like "Adult Mike" and "Child Mike"?